# Given two objects, how to copy values from obj2 to obj1 without overwriting similar keys in obj1?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have Two objects obj1 and obj2.
I'm trying to add properties from obj2 to obj1, without overwriting similar properties

Here's my code so far :

```
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

function extend(objOne, objTwo) {
  objOne = Object.assign(objOne,objTwo)
  return objOne
}


extend(obj1, obj2)

console.log('obj1:', obj1)
console.log('obj2:', obj2)

Here's the result I'm having : 
// obj1: { a: 1, b: 4, c: 3 }
// obj2: { b: 4, c: 3 }

I'm almost there, but as you can see the `b` value in obj1 
is being overwritten by the `b`value from obj2  

my desired result would be :
// obj1: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
// obj2: { b: 4, c: 3 }

I tried using the spread operator but with no success
```

Comment: Why don't you do them in the opposite order? The spread operator is exactly what `Object.assign` does except it would look more like `Object.assign({}, objOne, objTwo)` since it's immutable. You should just do `{ ...objTwo, objOne }` to "not override the values of the first object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `Object.assign()` does not do exactly what you want (protect from overwriting target properties that already exist) and you want to directly modify an existing object rather than creating a new object, so there's really no problem just making your own function:

```
function extend(target, source) {
   for (var prop in source) { 
      if (source.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !target.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          target[prop] = source[prop];
      }
   }
   return target;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an empty object and switch the order of the objects in [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Then use the new object for an assignment to `obj1`.

```js
var obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 },
    obj2 = { b: 4, c: 3 };

Object.assign(obj1, Object.assign({}, obj2, obj1));
console.log(obj1); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(obj2); // { b: 4, c: 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to add properties from objOne to objTwo, thew will rewrite props from objTwo by those from objOne

```
function extend(objOne, objTwo) {
  newObj = Object.assign(objTwo,objOne)
  return newObj
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see other answers are correct. But I am assuming that you want to keep the key orders. then this could be solution:

```
function extend(objOne, objTwo) {
      Object.assign(objOne, Object.assign({},objTwo, objOne));
      return objOne;
} 

obj1 = extend(obj1,obj2);

console.log('obj1:', obj1); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log('obj1:', obj2); // { b: 4, c: 3 }
```

Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/5xufsg7j/1/

Comment: True, I want to keep the key orders, but I also don't want to modify obj2 and I think your solution is affecting obj2